# Accessing DOM elements without ID in using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How can I access the HTML elements of this form using plain JS or preferably jQuery? I want to access input fields (username, password) and button (login). I'm clueless since these elements don't have "ID" and class is also the same for some.

I'm working on a Chrome extension.

```
<form data-bind="submit: login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: loginEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-bind="value: loginPassword">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        <button data-bind="click: logout" class="btn btn-default">Log Out</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('form input[data-bind*="loginEmail"]')`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
  console.log('email',$('[data-bind="value: loginEmail"]'));
  console.log('password',$('[data-bind="value: loginPassword"]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form data-bind="submit: login">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: loginEmail">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-bind="value: loginPassword">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        <button data-bind="click: logout" class="btn btn-default">Log Out</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelecor(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), for example like this:

```
document.querySelector('input[data-bind="value: loginEmail"]');

document.querySelector('input[data-bind="value: loginPassword"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `input[type='password']` selector like this:

```
$('body').find("input[type='password']");
```